# Lunix server returning old SSL certs via Curl

Tags: unix, ssl, curl

When I try and retrieve the most up-to-date SSL cert info from a url on my Centos7 machine I keep getting some sort of old cached result.

example curl:

```
curl --insecure -v https://www.google.com 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* Server certificate:/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'
```

I know for a fact, and even Chrome knows, that my expiry is in the future, but the curl request always returns the old cert which has expired.

Is there some sort of cache on the machine itself?

Comment: Show the full certificate you get. Probably not the real Google one. Also since it is not about programming, your question is offtopic here.

Comment: I'd say it is to do with coding as my inital attempt was to get the most recent SSL cert via a NodeJS script. But investigations lead me to believe that this is a specific issue with Microsoft IIS servers.

There's a good chance this might lead to a code solution on those servers. IMO.

Comment: The Cert i get is their previous Expired LetsEncrpyt SSL cert, which expired on the 13th. 

Unable to show to cert due to data regulations

Comment: `www.google.com` does not use Let's Encrypt certificates...

Comment: "Unable to show to cert due to data regulations" This does not mean anything. Certificates are public and in various public logs.

Comment: Google is just an example. I've not provided the specific URL, sorry

Comment: Ok, so I just lost my time trying to help. You should not use examples like that, this is very bad practice even more so when you are not explaining that nor giving actual details (and the "certificate is not shown for whatever reason" is just wrong as certificates are public). Anyway your question remains completely offtopic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue looks to be around bad configurations of Microsoft IIS servers, and potentially any ISA's sitting in front of them.

Unless you fully remove, and reboot the server that you've updated a new SSL cert onto, there will still be intances of that server sending out the previous (expired) SSL Cert so you will never see the latest one.